# db:migrate has no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I edit my shema, and run db:migrate the database doesn't changed, but if I clear to version 0, and recall migration it's works, but I lost all database data.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how `db:migrate` works.  It maintains a table in the database called `schema_migrations` that keeps track of the migration timestamps (i.e. if your file is called `20090807152224_create_widgets.rb`, the `20090807152224` part is the timestamp -- and the line that will get added to your `schema_migrations` table).

You're not supposed to modify the `schema.rb` file by hand -- that file gets autogenerated as a result of `db:migrate`.

The thinking in rails is that if you want to make a change to your schema, you're going to **generate a new migration** with those changes and *then* run `db:migrate` (which, as a result, will update the `schema.rb` file appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

When you say you are updating your schema, does that mean you're updating the db/schema.rb file, or actual migrations?

If you're updating the schema.rb file, you should note that it will have no effect because the file is auto-generated.

See the comment at the top of the file:

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead of editing this file, 
# please use the migrations feature of Active Record to incrementally modify your database, and
# then regenerate this schema definition.
```

Comment: I updated 20101217121533_create_users.rb with one new row, but if I clear the database to version 0, and after call db:migrate it's works

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were changing a migration file.

Don't change migration files. Add new ones. You can have migrations that change say, the type of a column. There are times when changing old migrations may be helpful, but don't do it unless you know the consequences. As others have mentioned, don't change the schema either, but I don't think you were doing that.